Parsing tomcat multiline catalina log with ruby regex in fluent-bit is not working as expected
Below is my multiline log for catalina output:
> 21-Aug-2024 04:51:02.916 INFO [http-nio-16500-exec-3]
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP
> request header

Need as below:

Time: 21-Aug-2024 04:51:02.916
Severity: INFO
Thread: [http-nio-16500-exec-3]
Msg:
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP
request header

My current Reg exp:
(?<log_time>\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]+-\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}.\d{1,3}) (?:\s*)(?<severity>\w*)(?:\s*) (?<message>.*)

Not getting "Thread" as a separate field, tried multiple items. not working. Pls let me know

Got the Thread id, below is the regex:
(?<log_time>\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]+-\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}.\d{1,3}) (?:\s*)(?<severity>\w*)(?:\s*) \[(?<thread_id>\S*)\](?<message>.*)

